# Unable to add resteasy local module in Jboss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Failed to define class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap in Module "com.test:main" from local m
odule loader @4f4a7090 (finder: local module finder @18ef96 (roots: C:\DEV\jboss-eap-7.0.4\modules,C:\DEV\jboss-eap-7.0.4\modules\system\layers\base.overlays\layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.4
.CP,C:\DEV\jboss-eap-7.0.4\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/ResteasyBootstrap (Module "com.test:mai
n" from local module loader @4f4a7090 (finder: local module finder @18ef96 (roots: C:\DEV\jboss-eap-7.0.4\modules,C:\DEV\jboss-eap-7.0.4\modules\system\layers\base.overlays\layer-base-
jboss-eap-7.0.4.CP,C:\DEV\jboss-eap-7.0.4\modules\system\layers\base)))

09:17:27,157 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".POST_M
ce.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Test.war"

Jboss version 7.0.4

CLI commands used to add the module

```
module add --name=com.test --resources=C:\jaxrs-api.jar;C:\resteasy-jaxb-    provider.jar;C:\resteasy-jaxrs.jar;C:\com.common.jar;C:\com.data.jar;
```

Tried even making it a global module

```
/subsystem=ee:write-attribute(name=global-modules,value=[{name=com.test}]
```

Comment: The problem is due to resteasy dependency in jboss-deployment-structure xml.  It looks like a class in the resteasy module is using org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.   Make sure you have defined its dependency

Answer (score 0):

Resteasy jaxrs are part of Jboss 7. Hence there is no explicit need to add rest easy jars as part of WebInf-->lib or as part of module as in lower EAP version's of Jboss.

The below url gives the right way to overcome the concern
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JAX-RS+Reference+Guide